# Using C display data in hex from WAV file

Tags: c, file, wav

So it's been a while since i've coded in C but some strange things are happening. Maybe someone can just run my code and see if the output is the same. It seems to not be printing zeros and the 'The data output' doesn't seem to print.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <conio.h>

void main(void)
{
    int i;
    long n;
    FILE *wavFile;
    printf("The data output \n\n\r");
    wavFile = fopen("bigbrain.wav","rb");
    while(feof(wavFile)==0)
    {
        i = getw(wavFile);

        if(ferror(wavFile)!=0)
        {
            printf("\n an error has occured");
            n = ftell(wavFile);
            printf("\nThe value of n is %ld",n);
            getch();
        }   
    printf("%x",i);
    }

    n = ftell(wavFile);
    printf("\n\The value of n is %ld",n);
    fclose(wavFile);
    printf("\n\nEnd of File");
    getch();
}
```

The result I get from this is. Since it is a wave file there should be some place-holding zeros in there I think. Does anyone see anything wrong?

```
4646495212c524556415720746d6610100012b112b118
```

This is how I broke the data down by hand just by cross refferencing what I know should be there.

```
//Winamp says Unsigned 8-bit PCM; 1 channel; 11025Hz
46464952    //"RIFF"
12c52       //size: actuall size 76890, says 76882. My doc says correct because minus 8 bits for fields not included
45564157    //format "WAVE"
20746d66    //subchunkID 0x666d7420 but in big endian
10100012    //subchunk 1 size, expecting 16 
b1          //audio format
1           //number of channels
2b11        //sample rate: file should be 11025 (ox2b11)
8000        //byte rate
            //block align
1           //bits per sample... i think it cut off zero so 0x10 for 16
61746164    //start of data it's "data" 0x64617461 in big endian
```

Comment: You shouldn't check `ferror` unless `getw` actually returns with an error. Also, `getw` is an old and obsoleted function and you should not use it in modern programs.

Comment: You're also doing the read-loop wrong. I suggest you change to use `fread` to read the data, and then use `while(fread(&i, sizeof(i), 1, wavFile) != EOF) { printf(...); }`. `fread` returns `EOF` on end-of-file *or* error.

Comment: Also note that the data you print may seem wrong depending on byte ordering. And that some data are not actually 32-bit values, but 8 or 16 bits.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
printf("%x",i);
```

to

```
printf("%08x, i);
```

This will ensure 8 digits are printed, with leading zeros.

Also, when parsing your wave file, you will probably `fread` the header into a buffer, which you will examine, instead of working byte-by-byte<sup>1</sup> in a `!feof()` loop.

<sub>1 - actually word-by-word here, since you're using `getw`, which I didn't even know existed.</sub>